# Error in connection with SQL Server 2005 form Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2005

I am using built-in SQL Server 2005 that comes along with Visual Studio 2008. But when I try to connect to this server with my project, I am getting error for connection at `connection.open()`
The error message is

> CAN NOT OPEN DATABSE "FAS" REQUESTED BY LOGIN. THE LOGIN FAILED . THE
>   LOGIN FAILED FOR USER'ASEAN1\ADMINISTRATOR'.

I don't know what is the problem. Below is my connection string.

```
Data Source=asean1\SQLExpress;Trusted_Connection=True;Initial Catalog=Fas
```

If I write `Integrated security=SSPI`, then it shows that the key word is not supported. I tried to change authentication mode but don't get any idea how to change the authentication mode for default server that comes with Visual Studio 2008. I also don't know how to make users with this server.

Please guide me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such conditions occured when you run your program and if you encounter any error while dealing with database and you left your connection open...  In such condition your project will keep track of such open connection and this could be a kind of bug with visual studio that even if you clean and build the project this will not close your connection...

To deal with such condition... you manually have to close the SQL connection by closing your service or you just restart it...

This could be one of the reason...